# Grunt usemin does not replace asset with revved version

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I searched alot and already found some links but none of them solved my issue. I use grunt-rev to revision my assets. This works. What was not working is, that the revisioned files are not used if I execute task grunt usemin.

The usemin config looks like this:

```
usemin: {
        html: './app/views/environment/production/index.blade.php',
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['./public/assets/dist/stylesheets']
        }
    },
```

The directory stylesheets has a file named 58640bd4.default.css

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28754465/422064 It helps me. If in index.blade.php you include your css file with relative path like this */path/to/default.css* then usemin is looking for ./public/assets/dist/stylesheets/path/to/default.58640bd4.css